# SQL Exclude duplicate entries meeting specific criteria (traditional where logic wont work)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of duplicate accounts, being grouped by a unique ID that accounts are tied to. I'm using a roll up and temp tables to list the count of duplicate accounts to only include the count of duplicate accounts > 1. We have a field which is I'm making up for the sake of a generic example but the principle is the same.

- I need to exclude accounts that have multiple type a accounts.
- But I need to include accounts that have type a and b.

  - If they have multiple type b accounts, they need to be included.

Given:

```
ID      ACCT      TYPE
------------------------------------
ID 1    123      A
ID 1    124      A
ID 2    125      A
ID 2    126      B
ID 3    127      B
ID 3    128      B
```

Wanted

```
ID      ACCT      TYPE
------------------------------------
ID 2    125      A
ID 2    126      B
ID 3    127      B 
ID 3    128      B
```

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Please provide table structure and any attempts you have made. SO is not a code writing service but a volunteer Q&A to help troubleshoot earnest efforts.

Comment: The problem is that I cant do that, I work with non public information, and I'm having issues adjusting my query to exclude accounts with that type.

Comment: I don't understand the results you're wanting.  What is the purpose of the `ID` column, and why isn't `ID 1` included in the results?  I don't see any duplicate `ACCT` values in the data you provided.

Comment: It is looking for multiple accounts under the same ID I'm trying to remove accounts with two type As

Comment: Your wording is very confusing.  You say you're wanting to remove accounts with two type `A`'s, but what you really want to do is select the ID groups that don't have multiple type `A` accounts.

Comment: not quite. if the ID has type A and type B I want to keep those two accounts. If it has type B and type B I want to keep those accounts. If it has type A and type A I want to remove those two accounts

Comment: You say *multiple* in your question, but your comment indicates there can only ever be two per ID group.  Which is it?

Comment: Is possible one `ID` have `2xA` and `1xB`?

Comment: The reason I didnt indicate multiple in my given/want is because it is something I could tweak myself for lack of information given by the client and my boss. You are right though, I need to thoroughly review the content before I post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you wish to only select those that have at most one project of type `A` per `ID` group.

You can do this by simply excluding those with more than one `A` type:

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select  ID, ACCT, TYPE, 
            Sum(Case When TYPE = 'A' Then 1 Else 0 End) Over (Partition By ID) NumA
    From    YourTable
)
Select  ID, ACCT, TYPE
From    Cte
Where   NumA < 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didnt think about using another over partition by.

Answer (score 0):

- First having remove rows with more than one `A`
- Then Include those with 2 or more `B`
- Or those where have one `A` and one `B`

.

```
 WITH cte as (
      SELECT ID
      FROM YourTable
      GROUP BY ID
      HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'A' THEN 1 END) <= 1
         AND (  
                  COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'B' THEN 1 END) >= 2
              OR ( 
                  CASE WHEN
                           COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'A' THEN 1 END) = 1 
                       AND COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'B' THEN 1 END) = 1 
                           THEN 1
                  END = 1
                )
             )
 )
 SELECT Y.*
 FROM YourTable Y
 JOIN cte C
   ON Y.ID = C.ID
```